# Output URL for thumbnail image size

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the following code in ACF to display an image, using a particular thumbnail size using image ID.

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('services-hero-bg'); $size = 'hero';
    if( $image ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $image, $size );
    }
 ?>
```

However, I wish to be able to keep the custom size, but output the URL only.

I have looked through the documentation and found a way to output the URL but this doesn't allow you to select a custom image size.

### Update

The results of the `print_r`:

```
Test Array ( 
    [ID] => 158 
    [id] => 158 
    [title] => Marquees-4 
    [filename] => Marquees-4.jpg 
    [url] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4.jpg 
    [alt] => 
    [author] => 1 
    [description] => 
    [caption] => 
    [name] => marquees-4 
    [date] => 2017-08-28 16:17:52 
    [modified] => 2017-08-28 16:17:56 
    [mime_type] => image/jpeg 
    [type] => image 
    [icon] => http://localhost:8888/wp-includes/images/media/default.png 
    [width] => 1024 
    [height] => 683 
    [sizes] => Array ( 
        [thumbnail] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-150x150.jpg 
        [thumbnail-width] => 150 [thumbnail-height] => 150 
        [medium] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-250x167.jpg 
        [medium-width] => 250 
        [medium-height] => 167 
        [medium_large] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-768x512.jpg 
        [medium_large-width] => 768 
        [medium_large-height] => 512 
        [large] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-700x467.jpg 
        [large-width] => 700 
        [large-height] => 467 
        [small] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-120x80.jpg 
        [small-width] => 120 [small-height] => 80 
        [logo] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-400x267.jpg 
        [logo-width] => 400 [logo-height] => 267 
        [hero] => http://localhost:8888/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Marquees-4-600x683.jpg 
        [hero-width] => 600 
        [hero-height] => 683 
    ) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field type is `image` then `get_field` should return an array. Within the array there is a parameter called `url`.

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('services-hero-bg'); $size = 'hero';
    if( $image ) {
        echo $image['url'];
    }
?>
```

e.g.

```
<?php 
    $image = get_field('services-hero-bg'); $size = 'hero';
    if( $image ) {
        echo '<img src="'.$image['url'].'">';
    }
?>
```

*edit*

After you have added the output from `print_r($image)` I can see that you just need to use this to access the URL of the hero image:

```
echo $image['sizes']['hero'];
```

Comment: Thanks for commenting. The above does output the image url, but it gives us the full size url. I am trying to get the url for the selected size 'hero'.

Comment: Got it. Have a go doing doing this ... $image = get_field('services-hero-bg'); print_r($image); ... and then you should see an array with all sizes, within here you'll be able to get the URL of the hero image. You could update the question with the result of the print_r and I'll give you the PHP to use.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have updated my question with the results.

Comment: That's absolutely brilliant - I have been trying to work this out for ages. Thank you sooo much for helping :-)

Comment: Happy to help. Up vote the question if you're happy ;-)